# Не могу изменить зум браузера FIREFOX

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Работаю с python selenium. Когда пытаюсь открыть браузер в полноэкранном режиме, ничего не происходит, хотя явно добавляю аргумент:

```
options = FirefoxOptions()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--start_maximized")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

И главная проблема в том, что, когда открываю сайт, то не могу изменить зум браузера:  если меняю то все смещается.
А мне нужно, чтобы сайт сразу открывался в таком виде: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: картинка]